# maven2 war project depends on jar project

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I have a basic requirement.

I have 2 projects :

1. web app (Maven2 project)
2. A utility jar project (Maven2 project)

When I build the web app, I want it to include the utility jar. I have tried to add jar project dependency to my war pom.xml but I get below error. I am not sure if I am missing some thing very basic.

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) myJarProject:jar:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess these are two separate maven projects (not two modules of the same project)?  In which case maven will not know how to get hold of `myJarProject` unless you run a `mvn clean install` on that project first to put it in your local repository.  Then when you run `mvn package` on `myWarProject`, it will be able to find the jar project in the local repo.

Comment: I have tried clean install as well. both are completely different projects. My jar project is used in other modules as well. For some reason the maven is looking for the dependency in maven repo instead of local file system.

Comment: In that case, it would be useful to see relevant sections of your two pom files...

Comment: Do you have a <repository> section in your pom?

Comment: <repositories>
  
  <repository>
   <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
   <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
   <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
   <releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </releases>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
  
  <repository>
   <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
   <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
   <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

Comment: I have pasted above the repository section of my pom.xml in web project.

Comment: I think in this case you need to create a multi-module project, with both the war and jar projects as submodules; you will still need to state the dependency of the war project with the jar one, though.  I'm guessing you are experiencing this error because you're stating a dependency that lies within the project's reactor (that is, it is only satisfied when the project is being built).

Comment: I think it can be done with out sub modules.
This is one of the features of Maven2.
Project A (war)  ---depends--->  Project B(jar)
My Dir structure (Project A and Project B are neighbors)

Comment: This can be done without sub modules, and you seem to have the right setup.  Are you sure there are no typos etc?  Can you see the actual dependency in ~/.m2/repository somewhere?

Comment: Actually its more of a mistake on my side. I had given same groupId for both the projects. Once I changed the groupID, it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its more of a mistake on my side. I had given same groupId for both the projects. When I changed the groupID to make sure its different for both the projects, it started working fine. –